# mysql - add row wise different incentive

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am executing one query which is giving me output as I want. I am stuck at the last step of the solution.

**Query**

```
SELECT sum(`purchase`.`purchase_ammount`) as Purchase, `franchise`.`district_id`
FROM `purchase`

LEFT JOIN `franchise`
ON `purchase`.`f_id` = `franchise`.`id`

WHERE `franchise`.`district_id` in ( 
    select `district`.`id`
    from `district` 
    LEFT JOIN `region` 
    ON `district`.`region_id` = `region`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `regional_owner` 
    ON `regional_owner`.`r_id` = `region`.`id`
    WHERE `regional_owner`.`email_id` = 'balajibarhate10@gmail.com'
)

AND purchase.purchase_date 
BETWEEN Date_format(Curdate(), "%Y-%m-01") AND Curdate()

GROUP BY `franchise`.`district_id`
```

**Output**

```
+----------+-------------+
| Purchase | district_id |
+----------+-------------+
|  18151   |      4      |
|  24603   |      6      |
+----------+-------------+
```

**What I want**

I would like to add 5% in **Purchase** of the first row if **district_id** is 4 and 2% in **Purchase** of the second row if **district_id** is not 4. I want it in the query itself. How can I achieve this?

Comment: SQL tables and result sets do not have "first" rows or "second" rows, unless a column explicitly specifies the ordering.  You do not seem to have such a column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okay. Sorry for the confusion. But I am just referring to output by saying first and second row. Just for understanding purpose.

How can we achieve the desired output?

Comment: do you mean to say that if the district_id is 4 you want to add 5% of the calculated purchase back to the original calculated purchase and so on?

Comment: @BlackSwan Yes. Exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN district_id = 4 THEN Purchase * 1.05
    ELSE Purchase * 1.02 END) PURCHASE_AMT, district_id
    FROM
    (
    SELECT sum(`purchase`.`purchase_ammount`) as Purchase, `franchise`.`district_id`
    FROM `purchase`
    
    LEFT JOIN `franchise`
    ON `purchase`.`f_id` = `franchise`.`id`
    
    WHERE `franchise`.`district_id` in ( 
        select `district`.`id`
        from `district` 
        LEFT JOIN `region` 
        ON `district`.`region_id` = `region`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `regional_owner` 
        ON `regional_owner`.`r_id` = `region`.`id`
        WHERE `regional_owner`.`email_id` = 'balajibarhate10@gmail.com'
    )
    
    AND purchase.purchase_date 
    BETWEEN Date_format(Curdate(), "%Y-%m-01") AND Curdate()
    
    GROUP BY `franchise`.`district_id`
    ) A
```

Comment: Worked very well. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can we make sum of both the column to get the final value?

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer once again

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement.

```sql
CASE
  WHEN district_id = 4 THEN purchase_amount * 1.05
  ELSE purchase_amount * 1.02
END AS AdjustedPrice
```

Of course, you can adjust the assigned name of the calculated field as need be.